# Order DateTime, then group by Date (ignoring Time) + other field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to sort by Date and group by another field. Seems challenging because `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` clauses use the same fields for aggregations.

This is some example data:

| Date | Operation | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-13 9:12:00 | Visits | 2 |
| 2021-10-13 8:11:00 | Calls | 1 |
| 2021-10-13 7:10:30 | Calls | 3 |
| 2021-10-13 6:00:00 | Calls | 5 |
| 2021-10-13 5:10:00 | Visits | 2 |
| 2021-10-13 4:00:00 | Visits | 1 |
| 2021-10-12 3:20:00 | Calls | 2 |
| 2021-10-12 2:10:00 | Calls | 2 |
| 2021-10-12 1:00:00 | Visits | 2 |

I need to show groups of "Visits" and "Calls", on different days. The result should be:

| Date | Operation | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-13 | Visits | 2 |
| 2021-10-13 | Calls | 9 |
| 2021-10-13 | Visits | 3 |
| 2021-10-12 | Calls | 4 |
| 2021-10-12 | Visits | 2 |

Right now, I've tried:

```
SELECT
    CAST([Date] AS DATE) [Date],
    Operation,
    SUM([Count])
FROM Table
GROUP BY CAST([Date] AS DATE), Operation
ORDER BY CAST([Date] AS DATE) DESC, Operation
```

But it gives the following result:

| Date | Operation | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-13 | Calls | 9 |
| 2021-10-13 | Visits | 5 |
| 2021-10-12 | Calls | 4 |
| 2021-10-12 | Visits | 2 |

Here's a fiddle to make working with this easier:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=39bb598378b35603ca98c0c4733d8f92

I'm thinking now in adding a temporary table with an additional column called "Group", but I'm not sure if I can try a better solution. I've seen answers to similar problems, but the "Date" problem seems to be different

Could you share ideas?

Comment: Surely if you've got the order by date descending, then the 14th comes before the 13th? Also, the grouping on the 13th should only have one row for Visits

Comment: You need to explain your requirement a bit more. It is not clear why you would expect "Visits" to appear twice for "2021-10-13" and what conditions/logic should be used to make it so.

Comment: That what i think me too, but i think he take the change between calls and visits into account on the group, is that so @zameb

Comment: This looks like a variation of the classic gaps and islands problem based on a date and operation key. Search for "gaps and islands" and you'll find many examples you can tweak for your specific need. Nothing different about date, string, int. etc. in this regard.

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan, thanks for let me notice. Take into account that I'm fixing by hand data that has hundreds of records

Comment: @Alex, the customer wants to see if there are calls before and after visits. But we can call any other name, for example "GoodWork" and "BossAdvice", which would represent how much GoodWork happens after and before BossAdvise. The point is: how do you technically will solve this

Comment: Somewhat confused about where 10-12 comes from when your data is 10-3 and 10-14.

Comment: @DanGuzman, sounds very interesting, looking at it right now

Comment: Thanks for clarification. As @DanGuzman says, this is a "gaps and islands" problem. It is somewhat complicated but you can start [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/gaps-islands-sql-server-data/)

Comment: The problem is you don't actually want to group by date/operation. If you did, you'd have the correct results. What you're actually trying to do is group by a **SERIES** within a specific date, and there's no series field actually stored in the database to use with the `GROUP BY` operation. So instead you must generate this, and the gaps and islands suggestions mentioned by others will help you with that.

Comment: @Stu I fixed it for him. Sample data is all consistent now.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, thanks for putting a name on it "SERIES", I did not know it was a thing. Also, thanks for the edits

Answer (score 3):

As discussed this is gaps/islands problem which just requires isolating the additional distinct groups, using a running count and subtracting a count partitioned by each group of rows:

```
with grp as (
    select Convert(date, [date]) [Date], operation, [count], 
        Row_Number() over(order by [date]) 
        - Row_Number() over(partition by operation, Convert(date, [date]) order by date) gp
    from t
)
select date, operation, Sum([count]) [Count]
from grp
group by [date], operation, gp
order by [date] desc, gp desc
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=41492f17141b200ac49983bf97dafae9)

Comment: It works with your sample data, but as you can check here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fffe82d7cf3e1fdfde7a8665d34c5e8f, as soon as I add a Visit between the first group of Calls, the result is not as expected. In the fiddle the result it puts Visit as first row, which is incorrect... seems that this doesn't have solution without iterating through the data. --> Once the "Time" part is removed, Sql doesn't have a way to differentiate operations on the same day

Comment: If you want the operations reversed within each group you could just add that to the ordering? so add `, operation desc` ?

Comment: Yup, but the problem, if I expect "Call-Visit-Call" as result, and I obtain "Visit-Call-Call", reversing will give "Call-Call-Visit"... and this is not compliant with the expectations. I think this is a consequence of not allowing groups or partitions on *already* ordered data. I don't see a solution without iterating through the data

Comment: Understood and I suspect your initial sample data doesn't do the full requirement justice, it looks like you're missing some key data to allow for the correct grouping/ordering

Comment: Yes, another grouping field would be of great help. At same time, all the information is there, seems just like a limitation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably wind up using a CTE (there's probably a way to do it similar to how you've already tried though). Something along the lines of:

```
WITH x AS(
    SELECT CAST([Date] AS DATE) [Date],
           Operation,
           SUM(t.[Count]) as [Count]
    FROM [MyTable]
    GROUP BY CAST([Date] AS DATE),
             Operation )
SELECT x.[Date], 
       x.Operation,
       x.[Count]
FROM x AS x
ORDER BY x.[Date] desc,
         x.Operation;
```

Although; if you're going down the route of wanting to show something like:

> X calls came before Y visits, then there were another z calls before the end of the day.

Then you'll need something more custom, like the solutions that were linked in in the comments.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, as you said, I need to count calls before and after visits